# Javascript: Global variable loses its value when accessed from another js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, global-variables

I am making an app (game)  using `nodejs` and `socket.io`.

I have few javascript file, three to consider here: `userDetails.js`, `board.js` and `modal.html`.

For now let the `userDetails.js` file have one variable declared: `var myUserName`. As it is global, i expext it to be accessed from other files as well.

My `board.html` file loads the `board.js` file. The `board.js` file has this subcode:

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
    setUserName();
    . . . 
}
function setUserName(){
    var myUrl = window.location.href;
    myUserName = myUrl.slice(muUrl.indexOf("?")+1,myUrl.indexOf("!"));
    //here myUserName gets some value like "John"
}
```

And my `modal.html` is has this as subcode:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/userDetails.js"></script>
<script>
. . . 
document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = MyUserName;
//myUserName loses its value here. Its undefined.
showNow();
</script>
```

The `showNow()` function shows the modal.

**Problem:**
When the modal is shown, the username id shows "undefined" as the value. `myUserName` has some value then why it is seen as "undefined" in `modal.html` file.

Comment: Do you have it declared outside your functions?

Comment: `userDetails.js` file just has a one line code: `var myUserName`

Answer (score 0):

Its undefined because you are calling it with a capital letter `MyUsername` while you are declearing it `var myUserName`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a type as i wrote this question from my phone. In my code, its alright?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be forgetting to export `myUserName` at the end of userDetails add

`module.exports = myUserName;`

and wherever you want to use it add

`var myUserName = require("yourPath/userDetails.js");`